# differntial equation simplification involving $ e^{-x^2/2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking at some differential equation examples.
I could not make sense of how this equation:
$$ Ze^{-x^2/2} = e^{-x^2/2} +c $$
became that:
$$Z(x) = ce^{x^2/2 } +1 $$

(its a solved problem chapter 6 problem 6.10  Schaum's outlines differential equations  edition 3rd/4th)

Thank you.

Comment: is that $Z$ or $Z'$?

Comment: What happens if you solve the first equation for $Z$?  Of course $Z$ is written $Z(x)$ in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a differential equation.

Multiply both sides by $e^{\frac{x^2}2}$.

---

Expand:

$$Ze^{-\frac{x^2}2}=e^{-\frac{x^2}2}+c$$

$\times e^{\frac{x^2}2}$ yields,

$$Ze^{-\frac{x^2}2}e^{\frac{x^2}2}=e^{-\frac{x^2}2}e^{\frac{x^2}2}+ce^{\frac{x^2}2}$$

$$Z\times1=1+ce^{\frac{x^2}2}$$

In fact, $c$ does not become $1$ but the operands of $+$ are swapped when displayed. The term that has become $1$ is $(e^{-\frac{x^2}2}e^{\frac{x^2}2})$.

Comment: Thanks you Arash, is there  a reason c became 1 ?

Comment: @monk, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

They simply switched the order they wrote it in; perhaps this would make more sense:
$$Z=1+ce^{x^2/2}$$